# LDAvis HTML output from serVis is blank

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I'm trying to use LDAvis for the first time, but have run into the following issue:

After running serVis on my JSON object,

```
serVis(json, out.dir = 'LDAvis', open.browser = FALSE)
```

the 5 expected files are created (i.e., d3.v3.js, index.html, lda.css, lda.json, and ldavis.js). As I understand LDAvis, opening the html file should open the interactive viewer. However, in doing this, **only a blank webpage is opened**.

I've compared the html source code with that from LDAvis projects found online, and they are the same. This was built using Christopher Gandrud's script found [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-link-between-topicmodels-lda-and-ldavis/) where the LDA results come from the topicmodels package and used the Gibbs method. The underlying data uses ~45K documents with ~15K unique terms. For what it's worth, the lda.json file seems a bit small at ~6MB.

Unfortunately, this issue seems too large to provide sample data or reproducible code. (If I could isolate the issue more, then perhaps I could add sample code.) Instead, I was hoping if readers had any ideas for the cause of this issue or if it has come about before.

Thanks ahead for any feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've resolved the issue after realizing that most web browsers restrict access to local files. For Chrome, the .exe needs to be called with the option "--allow-file-access-from-files". Otherwise, no error is displayed opening the LDAvis output unless you inspect HTML elements manually.

Comment: You could also install the servr package which will start a local file server for you: `install.packages('servr')`

Comment: for firefox the variable to set to false is `privacy.file_unique_origin`, it can be done while firefox runs using the about:config tab